# using .instance interface on a class?

Tags: eclipse, class, interface, libgdx, instance

I'm following a book on libgdx and at some point the author uses *.instance

*note that class Assets is a singleton class*

```
@Override
public void create () {
    // Set Libgdx log level to DEBUG
    Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);
    // Load assets
    Assets.instance.init(new AssetManager());
    // Initialize controller and renderer
    worldController = new WorldController();
    worldRenderer = new WorldRenderer(worldController);
}
```

what does .instance do? and why did he use it instead of going through the declaration process...

```
Assets assets
assets = new Assets();
assets.init(new AssetManager());
```

I'm thinking it might just be for simplicity's sake but I'd rather clear it up now instead of misusing it in the future.

online documentation has many examples in its usage so its very confusing... I just wanted to know what it does in this specific case.

**Code available upon request**

Comment: The answer is in the question: *note that class Assets is a singleton class*. If you were able to do `assets = new Assets()`, it wouldn't be a singleton anymore.

Comment: I see, thanks for your response, I was a bit confused because I didn't know if the IDE would detect declarations with singleton classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The answer is in the question: note that class Assets is a singleton class. If you were able to do assets = new Assets(), it wouldn't be a singleton anymore." –  JB Nizet 22 hours ago